# Substitution Cipher Alphabet to QWERTY

Tags: c

I'm working on a program that uses ciphers. The Cipher I need to use is the alphabet to qwerty. So...

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
```

the program needs to take the encoding key

```
qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
```

and produce the decoding key.

How would I go about doing this? I've only done a Caesar Cipher in the past.

Comment: const or static const lookup tables/arrays.  Index with offset from 'a' or 'q'

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in C to convert a string input to qwerty cipher, assuming you're working with only lowercase letters, and using a buffer size of 500 for strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char* ciphertext = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";    // cipher lookup

    char input[500];                                    // input buffer
    printf("Enter text: ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);                 // safe input from user
    input[strlen(input) - 1] = 0;                       // remove the \n (newline)
    int count = strlen(input);                          // get the string length

    char output[count];                                 // output string
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {                    // loop through characters in input
        int index = ((int) input[i]) - 97;              // get the index in the cipher by subtracting 'a' (97) from the current character
        if(index < 0) {
            output[i] = ' ';                            // if index < 0, put a space to account for spaces
        }
        else {
            output[i] = ciphertext[index];              // else, assign the output[i] to the ciphertext[index]
        }
    }
    output[count] = 0;                                  // null-terminate the string

    printf("output: %s\n", output);                     // output the result
}
```

Comment: Magic number: 97 :((